# Problem triggering MouseMove event with object (VS 2012)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I've created a label the appears to drag when you left click and move the mouse.
I'm trying to get it to "dock" with another label but I can't trigger any of the MouseMove events for the second label because Label1 is in way.

[image]

Comment: I haven't thought this through to the point of being able to provide an answer but I would think that you could just use the same event that you currently are for moving the control and just do a hit test on each other control to see whether the mouse pointer is within their bounds and, if it is, treat that as you would a `MouseEnter` or `MouseMove` even for that control.

Comment: I can't see a Hit Test property/event

Comment: There isn't one. I'm talking about manually testing whether the cursor position is inside the bounds of each control that you want to be able to "dock" with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used both labels left and top positons, with some tolerance, if theyre close it docks